# Passing multiple generic interfaces to a method

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to pass multiple generic interfaces as parameters to the constructor of one of my classes.

The following code does not compile:

```
public interface IPosterGenerator<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> GetPosters();
}

public class Pinboard
{
    public Pinboard(IPosterGenerator<A> firstPosterGenerator, IPosterGenerator<B> secondPosterGenerator, IPosterGenerator<B> thirdPosterGenerator)
    { 
    }
}
```

I have about a hundred different types of poster generators. They all inherit from the IPosterGenerator interface. When I instantiate a new Pinboard, I need to pass three IPosterGenerators to the pinboard's constructor. However, every of these three IPosterGenerators will be of a different type. That's why I came up with this silly A, B and C.

Can this be done at all?

Comment: are you saying that the classes A, B and C exist only so that you can pass in three IPosterGenerator parameters to the constructor?

Comment: No no. I have about a hundred classes (like A, B and C).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you probably want to make `Pinboard` generic:

```
public class Pinboard<T1, T2, T3>
{
    public Pinboard(IPosterGenerator<T1> generator1,
                    IPosterGenerator<T2> generator2,
                    IPosterGenerator<T3> generator3)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

To make it easier to call, you can *also* create a non-generic class with a generic method:

```
public static class Pinboard
{
    public static Pinboard<T1, T2, T3> Create(IPosterGenerator<T1> generator1,
                                              IPosterGenerator<T2> generator2,
                                              IPosterGenerator<T3> generator3)
    {
        return new Pinboard<T1, T2, T3>(generator1, generator2, generator3);
    }
}
```

Then if you've already got the generators, you can just call:

```
// Or whatever...
var board = Pinboard.Create(bigGenerator, smallGenerator, mediumGenerator);
```

Comment: Oh, ok. But what if I need a constructor with 4 generators? Or maybe a whole collection of generators? Sorry, I wasn't precise enough...

Comment: @IngmarBode Well, they won't be able to all be in a collection unless they have the same type, or a [useful] common base type.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks to all of you guys. That was fast :-)

Comment: Ups, maybe I was too fast. @JonSkeet: I liked your second solution (with the non-generic class). However, it does not compile: The non-generic type 'Pinboard' cannot be used with type arguments.

Comment: Sorry. My fault. Your second snippet was not an alternative solution, but as you clearly mentioned with "also" just some helpful utility class.

Comment: The bad news is: 1. It still does not compile: "The type or namespace name 'T1' could not be found." Same error message for T2 and T3. And 2: What if I want to be completely independent from the amount of poster generators that I pass to the Pinboard class. In other words: Would I have to come up with separate class definitions like public class Pinboard<T1, T2, T3>, public class Pinboard<T1, T2, T3, T4>, public class Pinboard<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5> and so on? I hope there is something more flexible... Thanks again for your help, guys.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to have your class declared generic with A, B & C as well. Something like this:

```
public class Pinboard<A,B,C> {
  public Pinboard(IPosterGenerator<A> firstPosterGenerator,
                  IPosterGenerator<B> secondPosterGenerator,
                  IPosterGenerator<C> thirdPosterGenerator) { 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry again for not being precise enough in my original question. Here is what I found to be ok for me (and flexible enough for my needs):

```
public interface IPosterGenerator
{
}

public interface IPosterGenerator<T> : IPosterGenerator
{
    IQueryable<T> GetPosters();
}

public class Pinboard
{
    public Pinboard(List<IPosterGenerator> generators) 
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks again for all your support, guys!

Comment: Well, no. I was wrong. Does not really work for me. I set up a completely new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962110/use-a-list-of-generic-interfaces